# Showing / Hiding a div depending on Select value

Tags: jquery

Once again, I am having trouble with Jquery (i'm getting better at it though!), I'm trying to have it so when i change the selected option of a "" tab, it'll show an input that is relevant to the selected option and hide all others.

this is what i've got so far;

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
      $('select').prop("selectedIndex", -1);
      var showSomeClass = $('#placeholder_type').val();
      $('#changling').children().addClass('hidden');
      if($('#changling').children().attr('id') == showSomeClass)
      {
          $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      }
      else
      {
          $(this).addClass('hidden');
      }
    });
</script>
```

but it's not exactly working out how i want it too... i think its probably got something to do with the fact that i'm coming at this like PHP instead of Javascript.

Comment: Why not bind the `.change()` function to the `<select>` element?

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dFhz5/

Comment: @Terry how do i do that exactly? I'm relatively new to Jquery.

Comment: p/s: You do not have jQuery loaded in your fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `.change()` event to the `<select>` element, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide all #changling children onload
    $('#changling > input').addClass('hidden');

    // Bind change event to <select> element
    $('#placeholder_type').change(function() {

        // Hide everything first
        $('#changling > input').addClass('hidden');

        // And then decide which one to display
        var opt = $('#placeholder_type option:selected').val();
        $('#changling').children('#' + opt).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Note: I have added a placeholder attribute to your 'stars' and 'ship' input fields so that you can see the select option is indeed showing the relevant input fields :)

See updated fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/dFhz5/3/

Comment: @user1030841 Might want to look at indenting your code for better readability ;) and you're welcome :)

Comment: My code is indented, my browser doesn't like to keep the C&P'd indents. :) thanks again